# Android studio didn't detect my device (Windows 8.1)

Tags: android, adb

i have tried some ways to solve this, but still got nothing. 
from kill `adb`, delete `.android`, copy `adb.exe` to other directory until restart many times.

please help, i have to continue my project.

Comment: how about install your device driver?

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: Randyka Yudhistira , i have been install thr driver, but still didnt work. I have tried install and reinstall again.

Comment: Ruan: samsung galaxy e5 and Sony experia SP

Comment: enable your device debugging option. by settings-> about device->build and then countinuosly tap this option so your developer options will enabled and then select debugging mode in developer option

Comment: Sud17:  in this case i have run my device as emulator before. But this problem came since 2 days ago.

Comment: Control Panel -> Device Manager

Does it pick up your phone there? "SAMSUNG Android Phone"

Comment: Yes sir. It appears on device manajer.. still didn't work 

Answer (score 2):

Make sure usb debugging is on in **developer options** and you have installed ADB drivers for your device in your PC.

You should also check whether if adb integration is on in android studio.

**Android Studio** < **Tools** < **Android** < **Enable ADB Integration** is ticked.

Comment: Already sir. But still no good result. I have no idea why it happened,

Comment: have tried connecting any other device and confirm that this fault is device specific or not?

Comment: Yes i have sir. 2 my devices and 2 of my friend. There is no spesific message i got sir. Just undetected.